# Can't access to Object in JSON from server response

Tags: angularjs, autobahn

I'm using following code to get the data from the server:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'URL',
  data: $.param({"KEY" : "VALUE"}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function(response){
            deferred.resolve(response.data.data);
        }, function(response){

        });

return deferred.promise;
```

**Returned value deferred.promise**

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
  $$state:Object
    status:1
    value:Object
      server_time:XXXXXXXX
```

I tried it with deferred.promise.$$state but what i get is state: 0

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: in your response you got status 1 so it is ok. to access you should do like  `deferred.resolve(response.promise.$$state);` this will make you to access the **$$state** object

Comment: @MohanGopi thanks for your quick answer, but when I do that, I get 'undefined' for my server_time... In `return deffered.promise` I get the server_time with the right value, but as I mentioned in my question, I can't access to that value....

Comment: may be its because you have two times $$state field in your response

Comment: No sry, It's undefined because at this time there is no $$state... only config, data, state, headers and stateText

Comment: sorry i am not understand you

Comment: I think the variables are a little bit confusing, I changed it in my question.

Comment: try this response.$$state  check this in your console in your console

Comment: It's undefined, this value is only accessible in deferred.promise